# Kubernetes terraform, use EOF for apply inside null_resource

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

Terraform Kubernetes doesn't allow use of anything other than `apiVersion: v1`. However I wanted to work around that by using the `null_resource` provisioner to run `kubectl apply -f ...` and `kubectl delete -f ...` (with `when = "destroy"`).

I've attempted to get this to work using the kubernetes apply EOF pattern, but haven't managed it just yet.

Here is where I've gotten to but it seems the `|` is an illegal char.

Also hoping I could pull the yaml string out into a multiline variable so I don't have to repeat it in the null resource.

```
resource "null_resource" "res_name" {
  provisioner {
    command = <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
      apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
      kind: Ingress
      metadata:
        name: some-ingress-name
        annotations:  
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      spec:
        rules:
        - host: subdomain.example.com
          http:
            paths:
            - backend:
                serviceName: some-cluster-ip-service
                servicePort: 80
  }

  provisioner {
    when = "destroy"

    command = <<EOF | kubectl delete -f -
      apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
      kind: Ingress
      metadata:
        name: some-ingress-name
        annotations:  
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      spec:
        rules:
        - host: subdomain.example.com
          http:
            paths:
            - backend:
                serviceName: some-cluster-ip-service
                servicePort: 80
  }
}
```

Comment: This might work with `resource "null_data_source" {}`  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13420#issuecomment-294858906

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were some bugs in your code.

- You missed the ending `EOF` for the `<<EOF` (["here-doc" syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html#terraform-syntax))
- A shell can't start with the pipe (`|`) command. The [`local-exec` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) runs the command in the local shell. Therefore use the [`<<EOF` stdin trick from the Github issue comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13420#issuecomment-294858906). Thanks for the hint. Didn't know this, too.

That code works on my side:

```
resource "null_resource" "res_name" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f - <<EOF\n${var.ingress_yaml}\nEOF"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = "destroy"
    command = "kubectl delete -f - <<EOF\n${var.ingress_yaml}\nEOF"
  }
}

variable "ingress_yaml" {
  default = <<EOF
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: some-ingress-name
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: subdomain.example.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: some-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 80
    EOF
}
```

I suggest to read in the YAML configuration from a file, instead. Then you can get YAML syntax highlighting and errors shown in your IDE.
Use either

- [`data "local_file"`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/d/file.html) or
- [`data "template_file"`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html), when you want to change something in the
  file.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I hadn't considered the `template_file` resource